# Jquery show not working on select options after hiding

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, jquery-selectors

Consider following bootstrap selectpicker:

```
<select id="parent" class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">Parent 1</option>
<option value="2">Parent 2</option>
</select>

<select id="child" class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">Child - Parent 1</option>
<option value="2">Child - Parent 2</option>
</select>

 $("#parent").on('change', function (e) { 
   var parentId = $(this).val();
   $("#child option").each((i,a) => {
      var childParentId = $(a).value();
      if(childParentId != parentId) {
         $(a).hide();
       } else { $(a).show() }
  });
   $("#child").selectpicker("refresh")
 });
```

No matther what I do, the $(a).show() has no effect.
What I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `$(this)` to get the dom but not `$(a)`

Update: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y9mqs3b4/)

```js
 $("#parent").on('change', function (e) { 
   var parentId = $(this).val();
   $("#child option").each(function() {
      var childParentId =  $(this).val();
      if(childParentId != parentId) {
          $(this).hide();
       } else { $(this).show() }
  });
   // $("#child").selectpicker("refresh")
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="parent" class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">Parent 1</option>
<option value="2">Parent 2</option>
</select>

<select id="child" class="selectpicker">
<option value="1">Child - Parent 1</option>
<option value="2">Child - Parent 2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: With the selectpicker class, the outcome is different, options in child select are not displayed.

Comment: @Debunkar I added the jsfiddle, its working right now

Comment: Hi Alex. I have identified the root cause of the issue, it seems that the 'data-size' attribute on the select (not in the example) is basically tiggering the issue. To be more specific, when I have this attribute on the select, whenever I try to hide the options INCLUDING the first option from select, it will hide everything. If I don't hide first option, it will work ok.  However, If I remove the data-size attribute, all is ok. I m not sure why does it have this behaviour. Any ideas ?

Comment: ...I used latest version of bootstrap select, it seems fine now...Thanks for your time Alex.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in this line

`var childParentId = $(a).value();`

you use `value()` the correct syntax is `val()`